# MKMapViewprevent user from zooming out past a certain range

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, mkmapview

I have a lot of pin annotations on the MKMapView in my app, the iPhone gets very slow and unresponsive when a lot of them are in view on the map. I would like the user to be able to zoom, but not out past a certain level, such as 2km squared or something.

Here's what I've got:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

[[BicycleLDNService sharedService] requestLocationForClient:self];

CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;

CLLocation *deviceLocation = [[BicycleLDNService sharedService] deviceLocation];

zoomLocation.latitude = deviceLocation.coordinate.latitude;
zoomLocation.longitude = deviceLocation.coordinate.longitude;

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*kMetresPerKilometre, 0.5*kMetresPerKilometre);

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];                

[self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
```

}

Is there some sort of property or delegate method I can employ? Couldn't find anything useful on google or here!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The span defines how much of the map at the given point should be visible and is also how you set the zoom level. 
You can access this by using

```
region.span.latitute=0.5;
region.span.longitude=0.6;
```

Check the zoom level of the map and then set the zoomEnabled Property NO.

```
mapView.zoomEnabled=NO;
```